# Nekudot in Word 2010

Tags: vowels-nekudot

How do I add [nekudot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud) (vowel points) to Hebrew text in Word 2010 on Windows 8?

With older versions of Windows I would follow [these instructions](http://www.qsm.co.il/Hebrew/wniqud.htm): place the cursor after the letter I wanted to add to, enter caps-lock mode, and press shift + the key code for the particular nikkud.  This doesn't work in Word 2010, however.  What do I do instead?

Comment: Seems like a superuser question

Comment: That's what I thought too, but superuser didn't know. I figured there must be someone here with the same problem.

Comment: Already [asked](http://superuser.com/q/685582) on Super User (so I won't migrate like I was about to).

Comment: @Eliyahu go take a look now :)

Comment: Oh thank you! Well I was right, I did have to come here to get my answer over there.

Comment: For future reference, it would have been fine for you to pop into [chat] to ask folks to look at it there (to save you the effort of posting the question).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use alt-codes. [Here](http://www.etz-hayim.com/hebrew/technical_resources/nikkudot.pdf) is a PDF chart. Be sure to read the instructions on the bottom of it. If you do any significant amount of work with this, I recommend a keyboard macro program to save a lot of aggravation.